# Best book for automata theory and compiler design?

Tags: reference-request, formal-languages, automata

I am currently pursuing my M.Tech in **Digital Image Processing**, I want to take admission in PhD program using subjects either **Formal Language and Automata Theory** or **Compiler Design**, Can anyone please suggest me books which covers.

1. Very basic concepts of these subjects.
2. Very depth knowledge of these subjects.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985837/compiler-design-resources

Answer (score 2):

Best books :

Formal Language and Automata Theory :

1. [An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata Paperback – 2011](http://www.amazon.in/An-Introduction-Formal-Languages-Automata/dp/9380853289/ref=as_sl_pc_tf_til?tag=gc0a41-21&linkCode=w00&linkId=&creativeASIN=9380853289) by  Peter Linz.
2. [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Automata-Theory-Languages-Computation/dp/B007YTM814/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1448972116&sr=8-2-fkmr0&keywords=toc%20ullman) by Jeffrey D. Ullman.

---

Compiler Design :

1. [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://www.amazon.in/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0321486811/ref=sr_1_sc_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1448972710&sr=8-2-spell&keywords=complier%20by%20ullman) by  Jeffrey D. Ullman
2. [Principles of Compiler Design](http://www.flipkart.com/principles-compiler-design-624pp-pb-english-1st/p/itmdyuvnwwa5faun?pid=9788185015613&affid=arjunsure1) by  A. V. Aho

---

You can [visit here](http://www.gatecse.in/best-books-for-gate/) for best books.

Answer (score 1):

For compiler design, you may please refer to

1. A.V.Aho and J.D.Ullman: It is a classic
2. I.Holub is a standard text.

I read Hopcroft for automata theory.

On the OP's request, a few advanced books on Automata theory are W.Thomas, Languages, Automata and Logic and Elements of Finite Model Theory by L.Libkin.

also, A much advanced book in compiler design is by Steven Muchnick. I haven't read the last few books, but they have been given to me by my elder brother.

Comment: I already know about these books, I have read these books twice......

Comment: @MayankTiwari Then you must be atleast good. You yourself have asked for basic books!

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän He is asking for best books.

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän, 1.5 years before I used to teach these subjects in engineering college, hence I know basics of these subjects, I just want to know books that generally contains text from Base Paper of respective topics.....

Comment: @MayankTiwari I have edited my post. I don't think I have any knowledge of a Complete Reference.